# Spring Boot + Angular: CORS issue - getting same after configurations

Tags: angular, spring-boot, configuration, cors

JDK - 17,
Spring Boot - 3.2.1, Angular - 16

1. AdminController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200") // Through annotation
public class AdminController {

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> adminName(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok("admin");
    }

}
```

2. application.properties

```
cors:
  allowedOrigin: "http://localhost:4200"
  allowedHeaders: "*"
  allowedMethods: "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE"
  allowedCredentials: false
  corsConfiguration: "/**"
```

3. SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("${cors.allowedOrigin}")
    private String allowedOrigin;
    @Value("${cors.allowedHeaders}")
    private String allowedHeaders;
    @Value("${cors.allowedMethods}")
    private String allowedMethods;
    @Value("${cors.corsConfiguration}")
    private String corsConfiguration;

    public WebMvcConfigurer webMvcConfigurer(){
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) { // global config
                registry.addMapping(corsConfiguration)
                        .allowedOrigins(allowedOrigin)
                        .allowCredentials(false)
                        .allowedHeaders(allowedHeaders)
                        .allowedMethods(allowedMethods);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Integrate Spring boot with Angular client application and able to access data from it.

Note: macOS Sonoma 14.2.1, safari, chrome - not working

Comment: Are you using Spring Security? If so, then you may simply need to enable cors configuration in Spring Security.

`
 @Bean
 SecurityFilterChain security(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults());
  return http.build();
 }
`

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate your `webMvcConfigurer()` method with `@Bean` annotation, in order for Spring to pick it up!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).